# trato de tomar datos de HTML para usar en una función de JavaScript uso document.getElementById().value; pero no me lleva los valores

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

Aquí tengo todo lo que hace referencia a *JavaScript*. Un objeto con todos los datos necesarios. Sé que eso esta bien pero a la hora de poner los datos desde HTML, no me deja, me salen errores que no sé como solucionar. Así no da ningún error pero no toma los valores del *input*. Estoy frustrado.

```js
  
  
      let moneda = document.getElementById('m');
     function t() {
     let propiedades = {
        creditosTasmision: 1,
        moneda: document.getElementById('m').value,
        descuentoTrasmision1: 0.950138504,
        descuentoTrasmision2: 0.970452447,
        descuentoPagina: 0.70044843,
        descuentoStudio: 0.8
    }
    
    propiedades.creditosTasmision *= 
    propiedades.descuentoTrasmision1;
    propiedades.creditosTasmision *= 
    propiedades.descuentoTrasmision2;
    propiedades.creditosTasmision *= propiedades.descuentoPagina;
    propiedades.creditosTasmision *= propiedades.descuentoStudio;
    propiedades.creditosTasmision *= propiedades.moneda;
    let array = [];
    array.push(propiedades.creditosTasmision.toFixed(2));
    array.push(propiedades.moneda);
    array.push(moneda.value);
    array.push(document.getElementById('m').value)
    array.push(document.getElementById('m').value)
    array.push(document.getElementById('m').value)
        
     return array;
    }
    
    console.log(t());
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Creditos Trasmisión</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="funcionCreditosPagina.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="funcionCreditosStudio.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="funcionCreditosTrasmision.html">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="asistencia/css/estilosCabecera.css">
    </head>
    <body>  
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Inicio.html"> Inicio </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="funcionCreditosTrasmision.html">Creditos Trasmisón</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="funcionCreditosPagina.html">Creditos Pagina</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="funcionCreditosStudio.html">Creditos Studio</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>          
     </header>
     <main>     
        <form name="form" method="get" id="form">
            <h1>Creditos Trasmisión</h1>
            <label for="">Valor De La Moneda</label>
            <input type="text" id="m">
            <input type="button" value="todo" onclick="t()">
        </form>     
     </main>
     <footer>       

     </footer>
    <script src="asistencia/js/funcionCreditosTrasmision.js"> 
    </script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Disculpas por tanto *push()*. Traté de muchas formas para verificar. Si me pueden ayudar les agradezco. No sé que estoy haciendo mal.
He tratado de muchas formas, por favor ayuda. ¿que otra forma de hacer ese procedimiento de pasar datos de un *input* de *HTML* para convertirlos en datos para una función de JavaScript? me quedo grande eso les agradezco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un push es para agregar un elemento al array, que quieres agregar a cada posicion del array? numeros o cadenas? objetos? debo poder agregar mas de un elemento y que me lo muestre en consola? agrega mas detalles por favor es dificil saber lo que buscas...

Comment: Hola wilson, bienvenido, te invito a que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: @infinit3Loop__ lo que quiero es que el documen.getElementById() me tome el valor que pongo en el input del formulario id=form del html y los push que tengo hay se que son confusos pero solo queria ver cual me funcionaba pero ninguno de esos push o esos document.getElementById() me toma los valores del input

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que sale)

Comment: Yo no veo ningún problema. Quita el arreglo e imprime `moneda.value` dentro de la función y verás que refleja el valor de lo que tenga dentro. Si esperabas que `console.log(t())` imprima el valor, si lo está haciendo, cuando el input no tiene nada. Así que **aclara la pregunta**. Por cierto, no necesitas obtener el elemento a cada rato. Puedes acceder a el desde la variable `moneda`

Comment: @Mateo es que ese es el problema que moneda se supone que debe darme el valor que pongo pero no es así. cuando pongo el valor en la pagina y precio no el botón no me agarra ningún valor me aparece como undefined

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich lo que pasa es que en la variable moneda se supone que se debe guardar el valor que pongo en el input de html pero no es asi me la envia como undefined por eso no entiendo que pasa que estoy haciendo mal.  esto es lo que arroja luego de darle en el boton Array(6)0: "0.00"1: ""2: undefined3: ""4: ""5: ""length: 6[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tienes ningún problema, ya que te estás confiando en el *console.log(t())* que está fuera de la función *t()*. Ese *console(t())* se ejecuta cuando carga la pagina y nada más y por tal razón crees que no te trae el valor pero si lo trae cuando haces clic al boton "todo". Pon el *console.log(array)* en la función *t()* antes del *return array* y verás los datos correctos.

Por otro lado, si quieres que el *console.log* que esta por fuera de la función *t()*, entonces al *input* ponle un valor predeterminado *value='123'* y veras que ahora se muestra ese valor.

Al cargar la pagina el input no tiene valor, por lo tanto *console.log(t())* no trae nada y solo se ejecuta cuando cargas la página. Sin embargo cuando le das clic al botón te trae el valor del *input text* (si es que tiene alguno o el valor predeterminado). Lo que pasa es que no estás imprimiendo ese valor dentro de la funcion *t()*.

*Nota:* Mateo ya lo había dicho en su comentario.

Comment: muchas gracias si ese era el problema no mostraba la función ya soluciones gracias nuevamente